# How can I find a list of my posts that are candidates of automatic removal?

Tags: support

What is the policy of determining a post subject to automatic removal?

Is it

- the post has no answer, and
- the post either has pure downvote(s) , or is closed?

How can I find a list of my posts that are candidates of automatic removal? For example, by a url with query strings, by search words in the search box, by SE data exploration site?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The rules for when a post will be automatically removed are explained in this FAQ post on the main meta:

[How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/203101)

The most relevant portion is:

> #### By the system:
>
> 6. [The system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user) will automatically delete any post [flagged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor) six times as offensive or spam (3 times on [English Language &
>      Usage](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9809/a-temporary-tweak-to-work-around-abusive-posting-patterns) and [The Workplace](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4117/temporary-anti-spam-measures-are-now-in-place)).
> 7. The system will [automatically delete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) closed, unlocked questions with zero or negative score having no positively scored or
>      accepted answers or pending reopen votes, that were closed for any
>      reason other than duplicate nine or more days ago and haven't been
>      edited in the past nine days. (`RemoveAbandonedClosed`)
> 8. The system will [automatically delete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) rejected migrations (questions created as a result of a question from another site being
>      migrated there, and later closed for any reason other than duplicate)
>      that are at least 30 days old. (`RemoveRejectedMigrations`)
> 9. The system will [automatically delete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) negatively-scored, unlocked, and unanswered questions that are older than 30 days.
>      (`RemoveDeadQuestions`)
> 10. The system will [automatically delete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) unlocked, unanswered questions older than 365 days on main (non-meta) sites with score of
>       zero (or one, if the owner's account is deleted), fewer than 1.5 views
>       per day on average, and fewer than two comments.
>       (`RemoveAbandonedQuestions`)
> 11. The system will [automatically delete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199860/a-question-should-not-be-deleted-by-the-user-deletion-algorithm-if-it-has-upvote) any post with a negative score when its owner's account is deleted, *unless* [the post
>       is a question that has at least one positively-scored
>       answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199860/a-question-should-not-be-deleted-by-the-user-deletion-algorithm-if-it-has-upvote/312594#312594).
>       (This doesn't apply on meta sites.)
> 12. The system will automatically delete any post, regardless of score or answers to questions, when its owner's account is
>       [destroyed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)
>       (only done for spammers and blatant trolls).
> 13. The system will automatically delete migration stubs (original site copies of questions migrated to other sites, which haven't been
>       rejected by the destination site) [that are at least 30 days old](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79051/why-was-my-question-moved-and-why-was-it-then-deleted-off-of-the-original-site/79082#79082).
>       Questions deleted under this criterion still have their revision
>       histories visible to everyone, and links to them redirect to the new
>       question instead of showing an error page. (`RemoveMigrationStubs`)
> 14. Posts with zero or negative score that receive six *recommend deletion* reviews (four on Stack Overflow) in the low-quality-posts
>       review queue are automatically deleted "from review". Posts can be
>       kicked into this queue either automatically or with *very low quality*
>       and *not an answer* flags, and can be removed from the queue if enough
>       *Looks OK* reviews are cast against them.
>
>     See: [The Community user deleted my question! What gives?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) at
>       *Help Center*

As for finding them, I suggest you search https://data.stackexchange.com for queries about "roomba". For example, this one looks promising: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/455567/open-question-roomba

Comment: The "live" search function has quite a few helpful features, too -- for instance, for #7 I think this is close: https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A674+is%3AQ+answers%3A0+closed%3Ayes+locked%3Ano+duplicate%3Ano+score%3A-99..0